# JavaFX TableView doesn't update outside of initialize method

Tags: java, javafx

I have an application which (for the purposes of this question) has 3 components.

1. The main view in question (with controller) which contains a TableView
2. The model for this view's table items (TableMessage)
3. A threaded listener listening for messages to add to the table

I am facing an issue with the TableView not updating when items are added to the connected ObservableList.  If I add sample data while in my controller's `initialize` method, the data shows up fine.  But when I call the same method to add from elsewhere in my program (the listener in this case), the TableView does not update.  While debugging I can see that the data is being added to the connected List (and the sample data is there so I know it is the correct object).

Controller:

```
@FXML
private TableView<TableMessage> messageTable;
@FXML
private TableColumn<TableMessage, String> messageIDColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<TableMessage, String> timestampColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<TableMessage, String> reportTypeColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<TableMessage, String> tNumberColumn;

private ObservableList<TableMessage> tableContent = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@FXML
public void initialize() {

    linkColumns();

    // this works
    addRow(new TableMessage("001", "today", "1", "10"));

}

private void linkColumns() {
    messageIDColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableMessage, String>("messageID"));
    timestampColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableMessage, String>("timestamp"));
    reportTypeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableMessage, String>("reportType"));
    tNumberColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableMessage, String>("tNumber"));
    messageTable.setItems(tableContent);
}

public void addRow(TableMessage row) {
    tableContent.add(row);
}
```

Model:

```
public class TableMessage{
    private SimpleStringProperty messageID = new SimpleStringProperty ("");
    private SimpleStringProperty timestamp = new SimpleStringProperty ("");
    private SimpleStringProperty reportType = new SimpleStringProperty ("");
    private SimpleStringProperty tNumber = new SimpleStringProperty ("");

// all my constructors, getters, setters below
...
}
```

Listener:

```
// same sample code as before, doesn't work here (reference to myController is set separately)
myController.addRow(new TableMessage("001", "today", "1", "10"));
```

I cannot see why the TableView stops watching after initialize.  As stated before, I confirmed that the correct tableContent reference is being updated.

Thank you

**Edit 1:**

Per question below, the parent to my view above (lets call it MainController) gets a reference to the above controller through :

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MessageView.fxml"));
        loader.load();
        messageViewController= (MessageViewController) loader.getController();
```

Then passes the `SpringContext` (used for the listener) down INTO `messageViewController`, which creates the listener from that `SpringContext`.

Then to give the listener reference to my `messageViewController` I call

```
myListener.setReferenceToController(this);
```

which looks like this

```
public void setReferenceToController(MessageController ref) {
    this.messageController = ref;
}
```

As a side thought, if there were an error in having the wrong reference to the controller, why would I see the sample data (recall that it was called in `initialize`) in the observable list when I'm tracing the call from the listener?

Comment: 1. Can you show how you are getting the reference to the controller into the Listener class? Are you sure it is the same controller instance that was created for you when you loaded the FXML? 2. Are you calling `addRow(...)` on the FX Application Thread?

Comment: Editing to reflect question

Comment: Humor me. (There is nothing wrong with the code you have posted, so the error is elsewhere. Getting the correct reference is the most obvious candidate.) Put `System.out.println("In initialize: "+this);` in the `initialize()` method of the controller, and `System.out.println("In Listener: "+myController);` in the `Listener` (immediately before the line of code you showed); verify the output from the variables is identical.

Comment: Updated above.  

Also, humor granted.  `Initialize` is called twice on application start (thus creating two controllers).  The controller that the listener has reference to is the second controller that was created.  I'm willing to bet that's where my issue is.  The reason I'm seeing the sample data in the ArrayList when I debug is because it was still called by initialize, but it's not the active view.

Comment: In your edit, you call `loader.load()` but you discard the result. The result of that is the UI node that contains the `TableView`. Since the controller you are using is connected to a `TableView` that isn't displayed, it's not much of a surprise that you see no results when you modify that `TableView`. Conversely, since you clearly see a `TableView`, you must be calling `load(...)` somewhere else with the same FXML and displaying the result. You need the reference to the controller created by *that* invocation to `load()` (not some other arbitrary call to it).

Comment: I have the FXML view called using an `fx:include` within my main FXML file.  I was under the impression that using FXMLLoader would allow me to get the exact instance of the controller being used.  Is that still the case and I'm just doing it wrong?  Or does this always generate a new controller?

Comment: By default, it always generates a new controller. There are a few possible fixes: I don't really have enough information to know which is the right one in your case. Probably the best bet is that you can inject the controller for the `fx:include`d FXML file into the controller for the "including" FXML file. Add an `fx:id` to the `fx:include` and then append the `"Controller"` to that id when you inject it. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers).

Comment: You hit the nail on the head.  The fix was exactly as you said (add an fx:id and bring in its controller using @FXML notation) and it worked great after that.  If you want to put that in a separate answer I can mark this as complete.

Comment: Answer posted (with some additional info)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default behavior of the `FXMLLoader`, when it encounters an `fx:controller` attribute in the root element of the FXML file, is to create a new instance of the controller class specified by that attribute via a call to its no-argument constructor, and to use that as the controller for the view defined by that FXML.

So when you get a reference to a controller via the code

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MessageView.fxml"));
loader.load();
messageViewController= (MessageViewController) loader.getController();
```

the `FXMLLoader` creates a new instance of `MessageViewController` and associates it with the new instance of the view defined by `MessageView.fxml`. Since you discard that view (you don't do anything with the return value of `loader.load()`), the controller to which you have a reference is associated with a view that is not displayed.

(Note that the `FXMLLoader` will still have called `initialize(...)` on that controller instance, so any effects of the `initialize()` method will be visible in the reference you obtain.)

From your comments, the view you are actually displaying is created by including `MessageView.fxml` in another FXML file. It is possible to inject a reference to the controller created when the `FXMLLoader` loads the included FXML file using the [Nested Controllers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers) technique. Briefly, add an `fx:id` to the `<fx:include>` element. The controller from the included file can be injected into the controller from the *including* FXML file by appending `"Controller"` to the value of the `fx:id` attribute in the name of an `@FXML`-annotated field. For example:

MainView.fxml:

```
<!-- xml headers and imports etc -->
<BorderPane fx:controller="com.example.MainController" ... >

    <!-- ... -->

    <fx:include source="MessageView.fxml" fx:id="messageView"/>

    <!-- ... -->

</BorderPane>
```

MainController.java:

```
public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private MessageViewController messageViewController ;

    public void initialize() {
        // messageViewController will be initialized and be a reference to the controller
        // for the included messageView

        // ...
    }
}
```

This may be enough for your use case.

There are a couple of other ways to modify the default mechanism for creating controllers. The most direct (which won't actually help in the case of `<fx:include>`s), is to remove the `fx:controller` attribute from the FXML file and set the controller directly on the `FXMLLoader`:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MessageView.fxml"));
MessageViewController myController = new MessageViewController();
loader.setController(myController);
// calling load will now inject @FXML-annotated fields and call initialize() on myController
Parent view = loader.load();
```

The main use case for this is for using controllers that need parameters passed to the constructor. You could use this technique to reuse a single controller instance for loading FXML files multiple times: I don't recommend this, as if you genuinely wanted two instances of your view to be active, things would go wrong very quickly.

Note that if you set a controller, and then load an FXML file which has a `fx:controller` attribute set, a runtime exception will occur and the loading will fail.

Another mechanism is to set a `controllerFactory` on the loader. The controller factory is essentially a function that maps a `Class<?>` to a controller instance (presumably of that class, but there is no enforcement of that). One important feature to note here is that the `controllerFactory` is propagated down to `<fx:include>`s; in other words when the FXML is loaded and includes an `<fx:include>` tag, the same controller factory is used in loading the included FXML as was used to load the surrounding FXML.

I often use controller factories to instantiate controllers with a shared model instance. I.e. given a model class:

```
public class Model { 
    private ObservableList<TableMessage> messages = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public ObservableList<TableMessage> getMessages() {
        return messages ;
    }
}
```

I do

```
Model model = new Model() ;
Callback<Class<?>, Object> controllerFactory = clazz -> {
    try {
        // see if controller class has a constructor taking a Model:
        for (Constructor<?> constructor : class.getConstructors()) {
            if (constructor.getParameterCount() == 1 
               && constructor.getParameterTypes()[0] == Model.class) {
                return constructor.newInstance(model);
            }
        }
        // no suitable constructor, just invoke no-arg constructor:
        return clazz.newInstance();
    } catch (RuntimeException exc) {
        throw exc ;
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exc);
    }
};
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(...);
loader.setControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
Parent mainView = loader.load();
```

Sharing a model instance usually avoids any need to pass controller references around, because the controllers can just update the shared data model:

```
public class MainController {
    private final Model model ;

    @FXML
    private TableView<TableMessage> messageTable ;

    public MainController(Model model) {
        this.model = model ;
    }

    public void initialize() {
        messageTable.setItems(model.getMessages());
        // ...
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MessageViewController {
    private final Model model ;

    public MessageViewController(Model model) {
        this.model = model ;
    }

    @FXML
    public void addMessage() {
        model.getMessages().add(...);
    }
}
```

(different structure to your application, but you get the idea).

The controller factory mechanism is very powerful. For example, [afterburner.fx](http://afterburner.adam-bien.com/) is a very lightweight framework that uses a controller factory to allow use of `@Inject` in FX controller classes, so you can just inject shared model instances.

Since you mention you use Spring, you could consider defining your controllers as Spring-managed beans. Then you can do

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = ... ;
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(...);
loader.setControllerFactory(applicationContent::getBean);
Parent view = loader.load();
```

Now the `FXMLLoader` will get the controller instance by invoking `applicationContext.getBean(Class<?>)`, passing the class specified by the `fx:controller` attribute. This way you can use spring injection to inject model instances (or whatever you need) into the controllers. And you can use interface names in the `fx:controller` attribute and let your spring configuration choose an implementation of the interface. For reasons mentioned above, it would be highly advisable to give the controller beans `prototype` scope (though injected model beans could be `singleton` scoped). Just some ideas...